# Couldn't understand conditional distribution and density function

Tags: random-variable, conditional-probability

The random variable X has a distribution function as shown in the graph below and
$ Y=X^2$.

[image]

Find

a. $P(1/2 ≤ X ≤ 3/2)$

b. $P(1/2 ≤ X ≤ 3/2 | Y ≤ 1)$

g. $P(X+Y ≤ 3/4)$

I couldn't understand how can I calculate this probabilities. I searched some books and I found formulas. For example;

$$P(a < X ≤ b) = F(b) − F(a), a ≤ b$$

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x  f(t)dt, x ∈ R$$

But I couldn't understand how can I implement above equations to my question.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot is your CDF, and therefore the maximum point it reaches is $1$. To be specific, it is $F(x)=x/2$ in $[0,2]$. For (a), you can directly apply the formula.

For (b), you'll use the definition of conditional probability:
$$P(1/2\leq X\leq 3/2|X^2\leq 1)=\frac{P(1/2\leq X\leq 3/2\cap X^2\leq 1)}{P(X^2\leq 1)}=\frac{P(1/2\leq X\leq 1)}{P(0\leq X\leq 1)}$$ 
And the numerator and the denominator can be found just as in part (a).

For (g), or (c) if you've typo, $$P(X+X^2\leq 3/4)=P(-3/2\leq X\leq 1/2)=P(X\leq 1/2)=F(1/2)$$

Comment: Thank you gunes. This is very good answer.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I understand all things. P(1  ≤  X < 2) how can I solve this. Because it is not X=<2

Comment: In continuous distributions, such as this one, $P(X=a)=0$, so $P(X<2)=P(X\leq 2)$. You'll have discontinuities in your CDF when some non-zero probability mass is cumulated around a value.